# Fortran: How to force "undefined address" for Optional array dummy Arg?

Tags: pointers, fortran, undefined

Fortran: How to force "undefined address" for Optional array dummy Arg?

I have a situation (long story, please don't ask "why") that requires "leaving in" an actual Optional Arg in a Call statement to an s/r that takes Optional array dummy Args, but still having them treated as .NOT. Present for some cases.  For example

```
Integer, Target :: n
Integer, Pointer    :: m
!
Real(DP), Target    :: ArrA(n)
Real(DP), Pointer   :: ArrB(:)
!
Logical     :: lSomething
!
m => n
!
If( lSomething ) Then
   n = 5
Else
   Nullify(m)
End If
!
Allocate(ArrB(n))
!
ArrB => ArrA
!
If( lSomething ) Then
   ArrA(1:n) = (/"... n values ..."/)
Else
   Nullify(ArrB)
End If
!
Call sr(ArrA, ArrB,n, m)    ! the idea is for ArrB, and m to "pretend" to be .Not. Present if they are Null.
!

....

Subroutine sr(A,BX,n, mX)   ! where the suffix "X" is my notation for Optional Vars
!
Integer, Intent(In)         :: n
Real(DP), Intent(In)        :: A(n)
!
Integer, Intent(In), Optional   :: mX
Real(DP, Intent(In), Optional   :: BX(:)
!
If( Present(mX) ) Then      ! this works correctly with Nullify'd pointer, when mX = "undefined pointer/array"
   !
   ! do something
End If
!
If( Present(BX) ) Then      ! this works INcorrectly with Nullify'd pointer, when BX = "undefined pointer/array", but works correctly if BX has the value "undefined address"
   !
   ! do something else
End If
.....
```

At the moment, the strategy I use is to create a Pointer to the Optional's in the calling sequence and pass the Pointer.

To be clear, this all works all the time, when the actual Args (pointers) are pointed to a "proper value" or array.  The question comes when trying to "pretend" that an Optional Arg as been omitted, by sending a Null Pointer in its place.

If the Pointer is Nullify'd, then the s/r receives an Arg with value "undefined pointer/array" (as it should).

The dummy Args are NOT Pointers, they are normal vars.

The idea, then, is for the "undefined" dummy Arg to appear as "not Present".  For example, in the line If( Present() ), an undefined var should register as ".Not. Present".

This strategy works perfectly for scalar Args.  That is, for:

```
If( Present(mX) ) Then
   ! do something
End If
```

then, if m is passed as a Nullify'd pointer, mX has the "value" "undefined pointer/array", and the If (Present(mX) ) statement operates correctly in that "mX is .NOT. present" (i.e. the "do something" is not reached).

Unfortunately, this fails for Optional arrays.  For example, in the above the exact same strategy (though having to Allocate a Pointer to be Rank consistent with BX(), and Nullify'ing that), the var BX has the value "undefined pointer/array" ... BUT the Present(BX) enquiry reports .TRUE..  That is, even though the dummy array var is "undefined pointer/array", it is still "present".  Then, even though it's NUll, the "do something else" is reached ... when it should not be.

My guess is that the act of Allocating the actual Arg, even though it is Nullify'd, creates a "nothing array" in memory, that is still "something" as far as Present() is concerned (though, for example,  Size(BX) is < 1).

By contrast, if the Optional Arg ArrB is actually omitted, such as:

```
Call sr(ArrA, n = n, mX = m)
```

then its dummy Arg, BX, has the "value" "undefined address".  This is different compared to "undefined pointer/array" via Nullify.

Put differently, apparantly, for the Present() enquiry to work correctly with array Args, the "value" must be "undefined address", rather than "undefined pointer/array".

Does anyone know how to force an array (dummy) Arg to have the value "undefined address" (instead of "undefined pointer/array")?  Or have the Present() enquiry work consistently with scalars and arrays?  Or???

Answer (score 0):

Your question is pretty difficult to comprehend. I assume you mean something like this. You definitely do NOT have to allocate the pointer or allocatable array to pass it in the optional argument.

```
program p
  integer, pointer :: a(:) => null()

  call sub()

  call sub(a)

  allocate(a(10))
  a = 0

  call sub(a)

  deallocate(a)

contains
  subroutine sub (ptr)
    integer, pointer, optional :: ptr(:)
    if (present(ptr)) then
      if (associated(ptr)) then
        print *, "present associated"
      else
        print *,"not associated"
      end if
    else
      print *, "not present"
    end if
  end subroutine
end
```

You can inquire whether the argument is present and also whether it is associated.

Output:

```
> ./a.out
 not present
 not associated
 present associated
```

Note that undefined pointer is something different than a not associated (null) pointer. You may not use the undefined pointer for anything, not even query its association status.

You can use the same for allocatables, instead of the pointers.

You definitely cannot have an ordinary dummy argument with an undefined address, that is forbidden by the language.

Comment: Cheers for that, but that is not a solution in this case.  I tried to avoid making the explanation longer than need be, but I did stipulate that dummy Arg is NOT a Pointer.  My setting involves calling hundreds of s/r's, and there is no practical way to re-write all of those and change their dummy types.         As for "cannot have undefined address", yes you most certainly can.  That is the entire problem at hand.  When the (array) Arg is ACTUALLY OMITTED in the Call, the dummy is "undefined address", and then Present() works correctly.  Just try stepping through with Watch ... it is what is.

Comment: Also, if I were to re-write those s/r's, my situation would be better served by keeping the dummy Args as non-Pointers, and instead use something like If( Size(BX) < 1) inside the If( Present(BX) ) tests.

Comment: "Undefined address" in that situation just means that the underlying machine pointer that is part of the description of the argument points somewhere that the debugger can't read.  Whether the value of that particular machine pointer means "argument not present" depends on the internals of the particular compiler - for some implementations the indication of presence of an argument has nothing to do with the address passed for the argument.

Answer (score 0):

For this to work (without making the dummy a pointer as VladimirF has done) you will need to buy (or write) a Fortran 2008 compiler.

Fortran 2008 added unallocated allocatables and dissociated pointer variables to the list of things that are considered not present when associated with an ordinary (non-allocatable, non-pointer) optional argument.  The rank of the actual argument must match the rank of the dummy argument, but this feature is available for both scalars and arrays.

If you don't happen to have a Fortran 2008 compiler in front of you, then you are out of luck.  Compilers that haven't implemented this feature may well pass nonsense when faced with actual arguments that are not allocated or dissociated, and their behaviour may well be different for scalars and arrays, because those are typically handled differently in terms of internal descriptors.

(In your example code your statement `Allocate(ArrB(n))` just leaks memory.)

Comment: Cheers for that.  Unfortunately, VladimirF's suggestion is a non-starter for reasons explained in response to his suggestion.  I'll see about F2008, but I don't think that my code "just leaks memory" ... although omitted from here for brevity, in the actual code all Pointers are Nullify'd/DeAlloc'd in the s/r that calls these s/r's.

Comment: I obviously don't know what your actual code does, but your example code above definitely leaks.  The statement in the question "though having to Allocate a Pointer to be Rank consistent with BX(), and Nullify'ing that" makes no sense - rank is a compile time property of a variable in Fortran <= 2008 (it can be determined just by looking at the declarations for the variable), allocating something does not change its rank.  Don't confuse the consequences of compiler implementation detail in the face of program errors with the behaviour guaranteed by the language.

Comment: It would take way too long to explain why what you say has little to do with my situation.  Rank consistency is required between the ACTUAL and DUMMY Args, whether Pointers or not.  I KNOW with certainty that what I say above is correct, since it works, and does so in much more complex and general context, without leaks etc.  Indeed, if I try to do it differently, it wont compile.  Let's keep our eye on the ball, the PROBLEM here is how to get Present() to act consistently for scalars AND arrays ... but thanks anyway, and I will let you know when I am "confused" :-)